# Is there multiband compressor for Audacity on Linux?

Tags: audio, audio-editing

There is C3 compressor, but people say it's from 2005, they couldn't make it work with current Audacity.
It has to be free/cheap for commercial use.

Answer (score 1):

With instructions for Linux there is a plug-in available for Audacity®

See [here](https://www.audacityteam.org/download/plug-ins/)